# ModelForms ForeignKeys and Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have an app that has the following models

```
models.py
class Student (models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
    #more fields here

class Paper (models.Model):
    #more fields here
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)

class StudentPayment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper)
```

and i have created my ModelForms for adding new student and Papers in very simple way

```
#forms.py
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student

class PaperForm(forms.ModelForms):
    class Meta:
        model = Paper

class StudentPaymentForm(forms.ModelForms):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentPayment
```

A student pays for a specific paper. I use the ModelForms to generate a form to add a student a paper or a payment. When the StudentPaymentForm is created the select field for paper contains all papers that were added in the database. Is there a way to make the paper select field contain the papers only for a specific chosen student (from the student select field) or is it a jquery(or ajax) task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django will create a default `ModelChoiceField` for the student attribute. It is possible to alter the queryset of a `ModelChoiceField`. The best way would probably be in the `__init__` method of your form:

```
class StudentPaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        student_queryset = kwargs.pop('paper_queryset', None)
        super(StudentPaymentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['paper'].queryset = self.instance.student.paper_set.all()
        elif paper_queryset:
            self.fields['paper'].queryset = paper_queryset
```

This will only allow papers related to the specific student instance. However, it won't magically update your choices when you select another student, you'll need Ajax/jQuery for that. You will, however, get a validation error when you select a paper that doesn't belong to the student you've selected, and you will have the updated options for the student you've selected once you try to submit the form (and it returns with an error).

Comment: Got it...so as i initially thought to achieve the behavour i want updating the papaer select field upon selecting another student is a job for sup...sorry for jquery or ajax

Comment: @Apostolos Yes, you cannot change the content of a page without either loading a complete new page from the server (like when you submit the form and it raises an error) or using Javascript (most likely jQuery/Ajax in this case).

Comment: Thx for your responses. Guess i shall have to rely on jquery and ajax

Answer (score 0):

I think running a query like

```
context['paper'] = Paper.objects.filter(student=self.request.user)
```

and then pass the context to the form will help.

Comment: Shall i do this in the view that generates the form?After the form is created in the view? I want the form to be able to "adjust", meaning every time a student is chosen from student select field the paper select field needs to be updated